# Dynamic array size in C

Tags: c, arrays

I've got following code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[10000] = "aaaaaaaa"; // this attribute may vary, so the length isn't going to be constant
  int aLength = strlen(a);
  int someParameter = aLength /4; // some attribute that's computed dynamically 

  char table[aLength][someParameter];
}
```

And on the table declaration I get error -> "Expression must have a constant value". How can I get over this ?

Comment: You may want to use `char a[] = "aaaaaaaa"`. The reserved space on the stack is now `strlen(a) + 1` instead of 10000 Bytes.

Comment: What's your compiler, with version and options? Your code is able to get compiled by `gcc` with either `-std=c89`, `-std=c90`, or `std=c99`

Comment: @PengyuCHEN, before `-std=c99`, variable length arrays were accepted as a gcc extension and were not standard.

Comment: @Shahbaz Oh thank you for your reply. Actually I've just posted a comment under your answer.. Thank you~ :)

Comment: Thanks Marius for the advice :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `table` as a matrix to which you will set the size with `malloc`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
  char a[10000] = "aaaaaaaa"; // this attribute may vary, so the length isn't going to be constant
  int aLength = strlen(a);
  int someParameter = aLength /4; // some attribute that's computed dynamically 
  char **table;

  // Allocate aLength arrays of someParameter chars
  table  = malloc(aLength * sizeof(*table));
  for(i = 0; i < aLength; i++)
     table[i] = malloc(someParameter * sizeof(*table[i]));
}
```

To have a variable size array in general you can use `malloc`:

```
// For example, allocate n chars
char *str  = malloc(length * sizeof(*str));
```

Comment: Are you sure this is what he wants? Your `table` may have unpredictable size!

Comment: I am updating to use `malloc`

Comment: @Dariusz would this work now? I was editing so that I use `malloc` to set the size.

Comment: I would remove the part about decoupling the declaration and calculation. It doesn't affect the execution in any way and would be misleading to readers.

Comment: @Shahbaz you mean doing `table = malloc(strlen(a) * sizeof(char));` and so on?

Comment: I'll edit your answer, so you see which parts I mean. Then you can revert or edit as you want.

Comment: If you don't mind, I also edited your malloc, to instead of directly give the type to `sizeof`, it would automatically deduce it. In fact, in the first `malloc` you had it wrong (instead of `char *`, it was `char`)

Comment: Great, thanks @Shahbaz . I haven't programmer in `c` for years and did not remember the definition properly.  I will leave my answer as you left it, so that it does not have errors. Cheers

Answer (score 7):

In the older C versions (e.g. C89), you couldn't declare an array with variable length. Non-constant array size made things complicated and wasn't overall very useful since the variable could be very big and immediately overflow the stack.

Nevertheless, it was added to C (in C99) under the name *variable length arrays*. Therefore, in the past you could only do:

```
int array[CONSTANT_EXPRESSION];
```

but with C99 or above you can do:

```
some_variable = whatever_expression();
int array[some_variable];
```

Of course, you should take care for the size of the variable length array to be positive and not too large.

You have two solutions therefore. One is to use `C99`. I.e., tell your compiler to enable C99 features. Your second solution, which I'd certainly recommend is using `malloc`.

Comment: Yes I also remember that in `C89` arrays with variable lengthes are not supported, however I've just had a test with `gcc 4.8.1` in which it doesn't trigger any errors or warnings with `-std=c89`. Really wierd..

Comment: @PengyuCHEN try `-pedantic` too. Nevertheless, `man gcc` says even with `-pedantic` some extensions are still not turned off.

Comment: According to wikipedia C11 has relegated variable length arrays to an optional feature - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C11_(C_standard_revision). If `__STDC_NO_VLA__` is defined then the C11 compiler does not support variabel length arrays :-S

Comment: @Jimbo, true. The C11 standard paragraph 6.7.6.2.4 states this. Nevertheless, it's quite likely (with the compilers I have seen) that either the compiler is stuck at C89 (...cough... microsoft) or if it is going to C11, it has already been through C99 so it would most likely have that feature anyway. Most likely exceptions are compilers for microcontrollers, which mostly support just parts of C99.

Comment: @Shahbaz. Yes, fair point... it is probably a "corner-case" issue.

Answer (score 2):

In C89 variable length array was not present. You need to provide the length which is available at compile time.

In C99 variable length arrays were introduced, therefore you can calculate values at runtime and use them to define the dimensions of the array.

Either use C99 with `-std=c99` flag with gcc and vla. OR use something like below.

```
char get_array (int d1, int d2)
{
  char **arr;
  int i;

  arr = malloc (sizeof (char *) * d1);
  for (i=0; i<d1; i++)
  {
    arr[i] = malloc (sizeof (char) * d2);
  }

  return arr;
}
```

and to free

```
void free_arr (char **arr, int d1, int d2)
{
  int i;

  if (arr == NULL)
  { return; } /* caller's responsibility to assign NULL to
               * uninitialized arrays
               */

  for (i=0; i<d1; i++)
  {
    free (arr[i]);
  }
  free (arr);

  return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need a constant expression inside the square brackets.
This would be valid:

```
char a[] = "aaaa";
char table[sizeof(a)-1][(sizeof(a)-1)/4];
```

If someParameter is truly dynamic (cannot be evaluated at compile-time) you have to dynamically allocate the memory for your table using `malloc`.

Comment: I'd like to add a note that `sizeof` here works because `a` is an array. If it was allocated by `malloc` then `sizeof` would have returned the size of a pointer. I.e. for a newbie reader, `sizeof` doesn't in general replace `strlen`